# Image folder reference - image not show

Tags: reference, interface-builder, directory, xib

I have a problem with some images, I create a folder reference (blu icon) with some subdirectory, I add /Immagini in "User Header Search Path", then in a xib file I add a button and I select an image, in IB I see the image but when I run simulator or device nothing, no image are show.

In IB I don't see the full path Immagini/folder1/image.png but only image.png, where is the prolem?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been around for years, apparently.  I don't think Apple plans on fixing it.  It *will* show up in your program if you specify the full path, but in IB it will show a blue question mark image.  Conversely, if you only specify the image name then it will show up in IB but not in your program.  So basically it means manipulating it with the image name only, then when you are satisfied switch it to the full path and put up with the blue question mark images.